# Can I check in more than one bag with Qatar Airways?

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I'm flying to Europe with Qatar Airways. Baggage allowance shows as 30 kg but I was wondering if I can take two small bags that weigh all together 30 kg instead of a single bag.

It might look like a stupid question but their website doesn't really explain it but I saw someone post somewhere that they checked in 3 bags and it was fine because all together they weighed 30 kg.

Answer (score 6):

This is the information from the Qatar Airways site:

[image]

You haven't mentioned where you are flying from so if you are flying from Brazil, Argentina, Canada or the U.S. then you are restricted to:

> 2 pieces, each not to exceed 23kg...

I don't think the above applies to you. This is more relevant to you're situation (since you are flying to Europe):

> 30kg

There is nothing mentioned about the max. number of pieces of luggage allowed, so you don't need to be concerned with whether you have one bag or two as long as the sum of the weights of both bags do not exceed 30kg.

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to comment in the above answer by karancan so I am posting the answer separately, The answer to your question is **NO** You can not take more than the 2 bags even if they total up to less then 30 Kgs. If there is a difference you can check your tickets, it is mentioned there how many "Pieces" you can carry. This chart is only for the reference to weight per bag, if you see. Source:- Tried traveling with 3 bags and was denied by Qatar Airways.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience: my company booked me with 43kgs baggage allowance and 7kgs hand carry. I tried to check-in my luggage with 43kgs but they asked me to break the weight of the luggage into 2 separate bags: one is my luggage and the other one is the one that I bought from Hamad International airport which was also sealed by the store.

So my luggage weighed around 32kgs and the sealed bag that I purchased weighed like 20kgs, but they didn't ask me for extra charge or anything. I also had my handcarry that weighed 10kgs + my backpack. So I guess you can carry 2 bags for check-in.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please use correct punctuation when posting on the site. It makes everything easier to read.