# Ryanair baggage - taking more than 1 bag

Tags: luggage, ryanair

I have bought Ryanair baggage up to 20kg. Can I take/give two bags which total weight does not exceed 20kg?

Related question: [Can I check in more than one bag with Qatar Airways?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20856/can-i-check-in-more-than-one-bag-with-qatar-airways?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell from [the FAQ](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage), you get 20kg or 15kg per checked bag that you pay for.

So, no, it's a limit per bag paid for. The better solution would be to try and fit the bag inside the other bag or get a really cheap bag and place both inside, keeping below 20kg limit.

Comment: I also think so. Just got confused because some airlines allow this.

Comment: With RyanAir, a pretty safe algorithm is: which interpretation of these rules gives least advantage to the passenger and greatest profit potential to the airline?  Oh look, that's the one they're using.